Feign client - fail to seralize response to object
I am using feign client to execute api Calls to external server.
i tried to implement a method that the response from server is array of objects.
json in response:
[
   {
      "schema":"http://json-schema.org",
      "id":"id1",
      "title":"titleHere"
   },
   {
      "schema":"http://json-schema.org",
      "id":"id2",
      "title":"titleHere"
   }
]

My feign client:
@FeignClient(name = "feginClient"
public interface FeginClient {
    @GetMapping("/v2/getSchema")
    SchemaResponse getSchema();
}

and my SchemaResponse:
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@ToString
public class SchemaResponse {

        private String schema;
        private String id;
        private String title;
}

When i am executing the request, i am getting an error to serialise.

Oh...JSON Arrays, ur using an object?
fixed:
@FeignClient(name = "feginClient"
public interface FeginClient {
    @GetMapping("/v2/getSchema")
    List<SchemaResponse> getSchema();
}

